# How to get the latest timestamp (Max) in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column called "**SYS_CREAT_TS**". I want the query to fetch the REV data where Status code is 2 and from the latest timestamp where status code is 2.

```
 SELECT RVSN FROM DATA_STUS WHERE DATA_STUS_CD = 2 AND SYS_CREAT_TS IN MAX(SYS_CREAT_TS);
```

**Some more detail**

Without the latest timestamp comparison query. I'm getting Revision Number(RVSN) as 2446, 2442.

But I want the latest timestamp between these two timestamps with their respective revision numbers.

1. 15-JUL-15 03.20.25.769000000 PM   -> 2442
2. 15-JUL-15 03.23.03.940000000 PM   -> 2446

The second one is the latest. Im using Oracle 12C. So, the result of the query should be **2446**.

Comment: Your question needs more detail. What is your table's schema? Why can't you run two subsequent queries? What does `RVSN` mean? And why are your column-names in uppercase?

Comment: And which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
select rvsn
from (
  select rvsn, row_number() over (order by sys_creat_ts desc) as rn
  from data_stus
  where data_stus_cd = 2
) where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with x as (select *, row_number() over(order by SYS_CREAT_TS desc) as rn 
from DATA_STUS)
SELECT RVSN FROM x 
WHERE rn =1 and DATA_STUS_CD = 2
```

If the data needs partitioning by a column, add it to the `over` clause so you get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RVSN 
FROM DATA_STUS 
WHERE DATA_STUS_CD = 2 
AND SYS_CREAT_TS  = (SELECT MAX(SYS_CREAT_TS)
                     FROM RVSN
                     WHERE DATA_STUS_CD = 2)
```

Would something like this work for your issue?